# Unable to connect to host via SSH tunnel from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunnel

From a new install of Ubuntu 16.04 I am unable to connect to certain hosts via an SSH tunnel.

Another oddity was that when attempting to establish the tunnel, via

`$ ssh -fN -L 2222:192.168.1.115:22 root@mydomain.me`

I was getting:

`Unable to negotiate with 1.2.3.4 port 22: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`

I fixed this by specifying:

`$ ssh -fN -L 2222:192.168.1.115:22 -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 root@mydomain.me`

One the tunnel is established, attemptng to connect to the specified host through it, via

`$ ssh -p 2222 -vvvv pi@127.0.0.1`

hangs for around a minute and a half at:

```
$ ssh -p 2222 -vvvv pi@127.0.0.1
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "127.0.0.1" port 2222
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2222.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/ansel/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4
```

It eventually fails after around 3 minutes with:

```
channel 4: open failed: connect failed: 
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

Connecting from other devices/OSes, such as ConnectBot on Android, works as expected.

Could anyone offer any troubleshooting pointers?